# Can package glossaries work in two-column mode?

Tags: glossaries, two-column

I am using the glossaries package to make a two-column acronym list. It works fine except that at the top of columns the list of letters collides with the acronyms in the second column. On the image below, I used the lupe to enlarge the effect for visibility. (MIPS is overlayed by a green X).
How can I get rid off of that? Either breaking at the end of the column the list of letters, or padding the second column or any other idea. If possible, I would like to avoid changing to single-column mode only because of this.

[image]

Comment: MWE please, everything else is guessing around....

Comment: For the effect of helping you, it would be more appreciated, if you included an MWE with your LaTeX-code.  Everything else is using the crystal ball.  Mine is lend to an Word user unfortunately ;-)

Comment: Is the *document* in two-column mode (through `twocolumn` class option or `\twocolumn`) or are you using a glossary style that implements two column mode such as the [mcolindexhypergroup style](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/#mcolindexhypergroup-style) or the [mcolindexspannav style](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/#mcolindexspannav-style)? It looks like you're probably using `altlist` in a two-column document, but we need to [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=altlisthypergroup]

\end{document}
```

By default the navigation line in the `altlisthypergroup` style is in the optional argument of `\item` which aligns it with the entries and group headers. This is fine as long as there's enough room on the line. If there isn't, then you need to redefine `\glslistnavigationitem`. For example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glslistnavigationitem}[1]{\item #1}    

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printglossary[style=altlisthypergroup]

\end{document}
```

This will now wrap with the line.